# requestAnimationFrame isn't canceled

Tags: javascript, animation, html5-canvas

I'm developing a game which is using the requestAnimationFrame. Here is the code for that.

```
Game.prototype.startLoop = function (arg) {

    var parent = this;

    (function tick() {

        parent.update();
        window.animationID = webkitRequestAnimationFrame(tick);

    }());

};

Game.prototype.stopLoop = function () {
    console.log('cancel the game now');
    window.webkitCancelRequestAnimationFrame(window.animationID);
};
```

The problem is that I get the message, `cancel the game now`, however the game continues to run because the animationFrame is somehow not canceled. I have tried `webkitCancelAnimationFrame`, `cancelAnimationFrame`, `webkitCancelRequestAnimationFrame`, and all the versions for requesting the animation frame in my browser: `requestAnimationFrame`, `webkitRequestAnimationFrame`. None of the combinations work.

The weird thing is that if I run `window.webkitCancelRequestAnimationFrame(window.animationID)` in the webkit inspector console, the game stops as expected. I added this code `window.webkitCancelRequestAnimationFrame(window.animationID); console.log('button test')` to the onclick attribute of a DOM button, and when I click it the game stops, but when I execute the JS `theDOMButton.click()` nothing happens, but I do get the message 'button test'.

Here is my user agent:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36
```

Here is a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/mJPMt/

After changing to this: http://pastebin.com/ewDXBT9C it works, but I think its weird since the request animation should stop without the need to check with a variable at every loop

Comment: First things first, use a shim/polyfill. Your code will break in everything that isn't webkit.

Comment: thanks but im using webkit so for now there is no need for pollyfills, they wont do anything about my problem.

Comment: Can you simplify the code you have into a small test that can repro the problem - ideally post it as a fiddle?  There's a good chance some other interaction is causing the problem.

Comment: You might also try changing the logic to check a boolean value before requesting the next animation frame.  It would be interesting to see if that changes the behavior in any way. `if(!stopped) webkitRequestAnimationFrame(tick)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call update after setting the `id`

```
(function tick () {
    id = webkitRequestAnimationFrame(tick);
    update();
}());
```

Otherwise it's stopping the old one, but the new one is still getting set.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mJPMt/2/)**

To address the issue that Vincent Piel brings up, you could always do `update` like a `promise`. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mJPMt/3/) using this approach. It's similar to the one in his answer, except you don't need a scoped boolean.

```
function update() {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    x += 0.1;
    y += 0.1;

    if (x > 50) {
        dfd.reject();
        return;
    }

    draw();
    dfd.resolve();

    return dfd.promise();
}

(function tick () {
    update().done(function() {
        id = webkitRequestAnimationFrame(tick);
    });
}());
```

Comment: there is an issue in case the update last too much time : another update will get called before the previous ended. With long updates and high refresh rate (120Hz for instance), it might really happen, especially if the evil garbage collector pauses the update.

Comment: @VincentPiel I updated my answer to include another possible solution that will definitely not have that problem.

Answer (score 0):

the behaviour you see is perfectly normal : what's happening is that you have the cancellation done in the update() method.
So what you are cancelling in fact is the *previous* rAF, and you launch another rAF whatever happened in the update.

```
(function tick() {

    parent.update(); // here we cancel the last window.animationID
    window.animationID = rAF(tick); // here we go again, we launch another rAF

}());
```

When you do it in the console, you will cancel the *next* rAF, hence the game stops.

So you need rather to use a boolean to have the loop to stop, and don't even save the animation id.

i don't know how you want to handle this boolean (closure / namespace / global variable) but it will look like :

```
var animCancelled = false;
(function tick() {

    parent.update(); 
    if (!animCancelled) rAF(tick); 

}());
```